# How to set Chinese fonts in modern Emacs

Tags: fonts, utf-8

For a long long time, my Emacs font definition in [X Resources](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/X-Resources.html#X-Resources) has always been:

```
! -------------------------------------------------------------- &ss ---
! ............................................................ fonts ...
!Emacs.font:                            6x13
Emacs.Font:                             fixed

Emacs.Font: fontset-gbsimsun
Emacs.Fontset-0: -*-*-medium-r-normal--12-*-*-*-*-*-fontset-gbsimsun,\
ascii:-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-*-60-iso8859-1, \
chinese-gb2312:-*-simsun-medium-r-normal--12-*-*-*-*-*-gb2312.1980-*
```

That was set more than 15 years ago, and had never changed.

Now, Emacs has modernized dramatically since, and X is using fontconfig to define fonts, and Chinese encoding has changed from gb2312 to UTF8 as default as well. So, I'm wondering what's the modern fontsets setting for Emacs is to work with Chinese properly?

More details,

- when give the example, please try not generalize but as specific as possible, assuming that I'm having all the MS default fonts in the system. I.e., please don't give example as `<your_font_here>`, but real thing like `Microsoft YaHei` etc.
- the [Fontsets from ergoemacs](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs_manual/elisp/Fontsets.html) is still giving gb2312 as the example.
- yet I can't get much from [GNU fontset docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fontsets.html) either

PS. I'm currently configuring my *new* **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial** environment, and for the first time, I've come to the point to be satisfied with my [Ubuntu 中文设置](https://gist.github.com/suntong/a532d5136713a7f1c67a3f118cc0d51c#file-ubuntu-md). My Emacs is the last problem to conquer.

Comment: Here the issue isn't the character encoding but the font rendering mechanism. These resources configure traditional server-side rendering, but you want to use fontconfig client-side rendering, which has generally better quality (it has anti-aliasing) and has far more fonts available nowadays.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Gilles. So to translate this general concept into concrete Emacs fontsets setting, what exactly should I do?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, that's why I posted a comment with a hint rather than an answer.

Comment: I think that this emacs package may give you some insights. https://github.com/tumashu/chinese-fonts-setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/tumashu/chinese-fonts-setup

If you google Chinese font emacs, this is the first result.

Basic setup:

```
(require 'chinese-fonts-setup)
(chinese-fonts-setup-enable) ; enable setup
(cfs-set-spacemacs-fallback-fonts) ; fix unicode icon display in spacemacs mode-line
```

By default, there are three profiles setup in `cfs-profiles`,

```
(setq cfs-profiles
    '("program" "org-mode" "read-book"))
```

You can switch the profile by `M-x cfs-switch-profile` or `M-x cfs-next-profile`

Surely your OS should have Chinese fonts installed at first.

Comment: Can you translate that? My Chinese is not good enough to understand what is done there. The result looks great though.